# I want my Wordpress image gallery to show only the first image?

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, gallery, lightbox

My goal is to create a Wordpress photo gallery which only shows the very first image of the gallery on the page and when a user clicks it , It pops up a lightbox with the rest of the images.

Moreover It has to be an easy-to-use solution because people will use it with no or minimal IT knowledge.

Is there any plugin or handy solution for my problem ?

I am looking forward for your answers .

Thank you ! :)

Comment: please check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: please try first if you stuck somewhere then ask Question.

Answer (score 1):

using [NextGen](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) can work.

This is a solution you can try:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16800/load-entire-nextgen-gallery-from-single-thumbnail